# Pandas json conversion messing with float precision

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, precision

After saving a DataFrame as a json string with `to_json()`, when the json is cast back to a DataFrame with `read_json()`, the initial and resulting DataFrame are not equals. I understood that there were conversion problems using `np.isclose()`, but since the goal is to save the DataFrame in a file for a later use, is there a way to prevent those inaccuracies ?

Please note that this is a minimal reproductible example, but the real data contains very precise floats.

Creating a DataFrame and making the conversion :

```py
initialDF = pd.DataFrame({
    'int':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'f':[0.3, 0.05, 0.888, 152.1, 8.12]
})

jsonString = initialDF.to_json()

resultDF = pd.read_json(jsonString)
```

Results :

```py
>>> print(initialDF.equals(resultDF))
False
>>> initialDF.loc[0, 'f']
0.3
>>> resultDF.loc[0, 'f']
0.30000000000000004
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add precise_float=True

```
resultDF = pd.read_json(jsonString,precise_float=True)
```